# Frechet differential in $L^\infty$ spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, frechet-derivative

define $L :L^\infty([0,1]) \to L^\infty([0,1])$, $f \to \cos f$.

Show that this operator is not Frechet differentiable at $f = 0$.

My idea was just to use the taylor expansion:
$$\cos (f+h) = \cos f + h \sin f + \mathcal{o}(\|h\|)  $$
to conclude that the derivative is given by $L'(f)(h)=h \sin f$. Is this correct? Thanks for any hints.

Comment: I posted the other cases too, because this was not so in my way edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be missing something, but since

$$\cos h(t) = 1 - h(t)^2/2 + O(\|h\|_\infty^4)$$

and $1 = \cos 0,$ it appears to me that $DL(0)=0.$

Comment: what would be the frechet derivative for all $t$?

Comment: @user160069  It looks to me like $DL(f)(h) = (-\sin f)\cdot h.$

Answer (score 2):

$L$ is differentiable at $f=0$ because, taking $A=0$ we have

$\lim_{\space \|h\| \rightarrow 0} \frac{\|\cos(h)-1-A(h)\|}{\|h\|}=\lim_{\space \|h\| \rightarrow 0} \frac{\|\cos(h)-1\|}{\|h\|}=0.$

Comment: Not sure why you posted this after I posted my answer.

Comment: I didn't see your answer. Sorry. Would you like me to delete my answer?

Comment: Ah, okay, no there's no problem. It happens, no worries.

Comment: I type latex very slowly. I really should learn to use Mathjax. In the future, I will try to read new posts before posting mine! At least I can upvote you for beating me to the punch on the answer.