# Frechet differential in $L_p$ spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, frechet-derivative

I messed up my last question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2509761/frechet-differential-in-l-infty-spaces/2509848#2509848). Should have contained all cases for $p$.

Does the Frechet Differential of the Operator $F: L^p([0,1]) \to L^p([0,1]),~~f \to \cos f$ at $f \equiv 0$ exist?

My candiate for $F'$ would be $h\sin f$, so

$$ \lim_{h \to0 } \frac{\|\cos h - 1-0\|_{L^p([0,1])}}{\|h\|_{L^p([0,1])}}$$

But I am not sure how to handle the $L^p$ Norm here, it seems completly different to $L^{\infty}$ Norm. I dont think that for every $h_k \to 0$, $\cos h_k -1$ goes to $0$ but I dont find any suitable example. I am thankful for hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not Frechet differentiable for all $p<\infty$. Take $h=\chi_{[0,1/n]}2\pi$. Set $f=0$. Then 
$$
F(f+h)-F(f)=F(h)-F(0)=0.
$$
If $F$ would be Frechet differentiable, then this implies $F'(0)=0$.
But
$$
F(h/2)-F(0)-F'(0)(h/2) = -2\cdot \chi_{[0,1/n]} = h/\pi,
$$
which is not $o(h)$.